# Fetch data from HTTP POST with CURL

Tags: http, curl

i'm new with curl

I want to try fetch simple text from html input using curl and send it to another website using simple JSON

this is the simple html code i make

```
<form action="http:test.com" method="post">
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

is there a way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: More specific? what language you use? is the "another website" have the same domain? How do you want to send to another website, using HTML form from client or other methods from your server?

Comment: im trying to send the data to some webhook for slack using JSON payload,im wondering how i can get HTTP data from that code

Comment: So you want to use that code to send a data to Slack's webhook, then get and process the response from Slack?

Comment: yes,i want the text be sent to channel on slack using webhook,well i want to know how to get HTTP input data using CURL,i had tried sending just text payload and it works following tutorial from slack but im not familiar with curl command which is to get data from HTTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to fetch the data from Slack, the nice way is to use AJAX to post the data. The following JS codes are modified based on [achavez's gist: Post to Slack using javascript](https://gist.github.com/achavez/9767499) and use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
<form action="http:test.com" method="post" id="the-form">
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#the-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "http:test.com"; // Webhook URL
        var text = $('#text').text(); // Text to post, get from your form
        $.ajax({
            data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
                "text": text
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: url
        }).done(function(data) {
            // do whatever you want with `data`, `data` is the response
        });;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: so the url is the webhook which payload is sent to or the url where data fetched?

Comment: hmm it seems doesnt work..i use it in js file on wordpress page

Comment: If you are using Chrome, Press `Ctrl+Shift+J` (Windows / Linux) or `Cmd+Opt+J` (Mac) to open console and see if there is any error.

Comment: -Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function -Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).boc_doesExist is not a function

Comment: @JoeAndaru looks like there are errors somewhere else. You need to pinpoint the problem. I think follow the error message by clicking the file name at the end of the line.

Comment: @JoeAndaru would you mind post the source code of file where error occurs so that I can help to diagnose

Comment: where to post it? its rather long so i cant post in here

Comment: @JoeAndaru I think you can place it in Github, Dropbox, Google Drive and send the link here is fine

Comment: @joeandaru change a jQuery version, use `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js` instead and have a try.

Comment: Some error had been solved but there still some error left https://github.com/joeandaru/asd/issues/2

Comment: @joeandaru Ok, try to remove the "including jQuery line", I think maybe you already have another version of jQuery on that page. If error still remains, post the URL of your page here or source code of your page on Github.

Comment: when i remove it i got another error https://github.com/joeandaru/asd/issues/3 unfortunately its on local area so it cant be accessed from outside,also im using the code on wordpress

Comment: @joeandaru try enclose all js codes with `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});`